How to detect that a built-in function has had its name imported over by another module
Backstory
A confession, I have used import * and felt the pain.
Specifically I had from pyspark.sql.functions import * and then attempted to use a builtin function that had been overridden by that liberal import.
Looking at how many same named functions exist in both, I guess it was only a matter of time before I snagged on a collision:
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> pprint(list(set(dir(F)) & set(dir(__builtin__))))
['sum',
 '__package__',
 '__doc__',
 'round',
 'abs',
 'min',
 'bin',
 'filter',
 'ascii',
 '__spec__',
 'hex',
 '__loader__',
 'slice',
 'hash',
 'pow',
 'max',
 '__name__']

Wish
I have experimented with being a little more proactive, to see what has changed in my global namespace, but specifically the builtins are confusing me.
>>> ORIGINAL_GLOBALS = globals().copy()
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> MUTATED_GLOBALS = {key: value 
...                    for key, value in globals().items() 
...                    if (key in ORIGINAL_GLOBALS 
...                      and ORIGINAL_GLOBALS[key] != value)}
>>> print(MUTATED_GLOBALS)
{}

I expected the above to list the above functions that had been hidden by the import * however instead it is empty.
Questions

Am I looking in the right place to interrogate the global namespace?
If so, is there something bespoke happening with builtins that I need to take into account?
And if there is something unusual with builtins, is there anything else that has the same side-door?

TL;DR
Is there a good, pythonic way for me to detect something having changed in the global namespace?

Builtins aren't in the global namespace; the builtin namespace is one layer up. Instead, import builtins and check that.
>>> 'sum' in globals()
False
>>> import builtins
>>> sum is vars(builtins)['sum']
True

Example with stdlib star-import
re has the function compile which overrides the builtin.
An additional step is that builtins is a module, so has attributes like __name__ and __doc__ that we don't care about, so we could simply filter all private names.
from re import *

import builtins

overridden_builtins = {
    key: value for key, value in globals().items()
    if (
        not key.startswith('_')  # Filter private names
        and key in vars(builtins)
        and vars(builtins)[key] != value
    )
}
print(overridden_builtins)

{'compile': <function compile at 0x7fd30bb83890>}

